# The time complexity of counting sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, asymptotic-complexity

I am taking an algorithms course and there I saw that the time complexity of counting sort is O(n+k) where k is the range of numbers and n is the input size. My question is, when the difference between k and n is too much, such as when k=O(n<sup>2</sup>)or O(n<sup>3</sup>), can we say that the complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>) or O(n<sup>3</sup>)? Then in this case counting sort is not a wise approach and we can use merge sort. Am I right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you are exactly right on all counts.

Furthermore, we can make stronger statements: when k=O(n<sup>2</sup>) or O(n<sup>3</sup>), we can say that the complexity of the counting sort is Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) or Θ(n<sup>3</sup>).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i just wanted to make sure whether i understood right

Answer (score 3):

You can still sort in O(n) time, theoretically.  If the range of values is say 1 to n<sup>3</sup> then convert to base n and do a Radix sort.  In base n the number has 3 digits, so your run time is O(3n + 3n) + O(n) for the base conversion.  Overall O(n).

Comment: you are assuming `O(1)` operations on base `n` numbers. It seems unlikely to hold in general.