# What is the most efficient algorithm to sort a matrix that contains elements in range [0,127]?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, matrix, counting-sort

Since the elements of the matrix are bounded then I thought to use a variation of counting sort and then the running time maybe could be O(n^2), assuming that the size of the matrix is n^2.

Assuming that the result should be a sorted one dimensional array of size n^2 .

Can I get a hint ?

Comment: What does "sort a matrix" mean? Can you give an example of an unsorted matrix and what the output of your algorithm would be?

Comment: Hi, you might want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599610/the-time-complexity-of-counting-sort

Comment: @Stef yea you right. I edited. Thanks

Comment: Okay. So what's the question? You want a hint? A hint about what?

Comment: look into [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) It has `O(n)` time complexity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the answer in your tags... Counting sort will beat anything else in such a small range as `[0, 127]`.